# Unable to connect to XMLA/Mondrian using olap4j

Tags: java, mdx, mondrian, xmla, olap4j

I'm trying to connect to XMLA webservice through the java api (olap4j) in order to execute MDX queries over Mondrian cube which is sit in BI tool hosted in localhost.

This is my code below :

```
 try {
         Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
         Connection connection =
                DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:xmla:Server=http://127.0.0.1:8080/jasperserver-pro/xmla");



        OlapWrapper wrapper = (OlapWrapper) connection;
        OlapConnection olapConnection = wrapper
                .unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
        OlapStatement statement = (OlapStatement) connection
                .createStatement();

        CellSet cellSet =
                statement.executeOlapQuery("select [Measures].Members ON COLUMNS\n" +
                        "from [FAIS_MED]\n");
        for (Position row : cellSet.getAxes().get(1)) {
            for (Position column : cellSet.getAxes().get(0)) {
                for (Member member : row.getMembers()) {
                    System.out.println(member.getUniqueName());
                }
                for (Member member : column.getMembers()) {
                    System.out.println(member.getUniqueName());
                }
                final Cell cell = cellSet.getCell(column, row);
                System.out.println(cell.getFormattedValue());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }


        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I will get this below error :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.slimani.bi_restful.testing.MondrianOlap4jDriver.getConnection(MondrianOlap4jDriver.java:18)
at com.slimani.bi_restful.testing.MondrianOlap4jDriver.main(MondrianOlap4jDriver.java:45)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.slimani.bi_restful.testing.MondrianOlap4jDriver.main(MondrianOlap4jDriver.java:48)
```

Answer (score 0):

The XMLA driver is not being found. You can see this in the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver.

You can download it from maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.olap4j/olap4j-xmla/1.2.0